# When writing to a csv file, why is each letter in a column?

Tags: python, csv, unicode

The code I am using:

```
import urllib2
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ongoing_armed_conflicts"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

fl = open('locations.csv', 'w')

def unique(countries):
    seen = set()
    for country in countries:
        l = country.lower()
        if l in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(l)
        yield country


locs = []
for row in soup.select('table.wikitable tr'):
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if cells:
        for location in cells[3].find_all(text=True):
            locs.extend(location.split())

locs2 = []            
for locations in unique(locs):
    locations = locs2.extend(locations.split())
print sorted(locs2)

writer = csv.writer(fl)
writer.writerow(['location'])
for values in sorted(locs2):
    writer.writerow(values)

fl.close()
```

When I print the code I am writing I get a `u'` in front of each element which I think is why it is outputting this way. I tried using `.strip(u'')` but it gives me an error that `.strip` cannot be used as it is a list. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `u''` is Python's way of telling you that the string is in Unicode.  It is not actually part of the string, so `strip()` would not remove it anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locs2` is a list with strings, not a list of lists. As such you are trying to write individual strings as a row:

```
for values in sorted(locs2):
    writer.writerow(values)
```

Here `values` is a string, and `writerow()` treats it as a sequence. Each element of whatever sequence you pass to that function will be treated as a separate column.

If you wanted to write all locations as *one* row, pass the whole list to `writer.writerow()`:

```
writer.writerow(sorted(locs2))
```

If you wanted to write a new row for each individual location, wrap it in a list first:

```
for location in sorted(locs2):
    writer.writerow([location])
```

You don't need to string `u` prefixes from strings; that's just Python telling you you have *Unicode* string objects, not byte string objects:

```
>>> 'ASCII byte string'
'ASCII byte string'
>>> 'ASCII unicode string'.decode('ascii')
u'ASCII unicode string'
```

See the following information if you want to learn more about Python and Unicode:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)